# Why are the following statements true?

Tags: inner-products, matrix-equations, transpose

Suppose we have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Consider a vector $ v \in R^n$. Why it is the case that

$\langle Av, v \rangle = \langle v, A^Tv\rangle $

for the inner product?

Where $A^T$ is the transpose of A

Comment: Note that $\langle Av,v\rangle$ is a scalar, which implies that it is a symmetric matrix ($1\times 1$ matrices are matrices too). Transpose it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$, one has the following equality:
$$\langle x,y\rangle ={}^\intercal xy.$$
Indeed, if $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ are **column** vectors, one has:
$${}^\intercal xy=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i.$$
Whence the result, since:
$$\langle Av,v\rangle={}^\intercal(Av)v={}^\intercal v{}^\intercal Av=\langle v,{}^\intercal Av\rangle.$$

Comment: sorry, perhaps I don't understand the last line. You define $^T xy = \sum x_i y_i$.

Comment: I am just using twice that $\langle x,y\rangle={}^\intercal xy$ and that ${}^\intercal(Av)={}^\intercal v{}^\intercal A$.

Answer (score 0):

In general for vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ we have that $\langle Av,w \rangle = \langle v, A^*w \rangle$ and $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$. In fact you get $A^*$ by taking the transpose of the matrix and then the conjugate of each term. But as all entries in the matrix $A$ are real in your case, the conjugation doesn't change anything. Hence we have $A^* = A^T$.

To prove the fact in the first line you can find some orthonormal basis of the vector space and then express $v$ and $w$ using it, expand and you would be able to find the entries in the matrix $B$ such that $\langle Av,w \rangle = \langle v, Bw \rangle$. This will lead you to conclude that $B = A^*$